# connecting hibernate to an Access database in network folder

Tags: java, hibernate, ms-access

I´ve got a problem conecting to an Access database.

It works when:
Database path: C:\database.mdb
and the conection string:

```
<property name='connection.url'>jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=C:\\database.mdb;</property>
```

But the problem arrives with the production database:
Database path: \serv-data\folder1\folder2\database.mdb
and the conection strings that I´ve tried are:

```
        <property name='connection.url'>jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=\\serv-data\\folder1\\folder2\\database.mdb;</property>
    <property name='connection.url'>jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=\\\serv-data\\folder1\\folder2\\database.mdb;</property>
    <property name='connection.url'>jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=\\\\serv-data\\folder1\\folder2\\database.mdb;</property>
```

Which connection string should i use???

Thanks to everyone!

Edited1: its a shared folder.

Edited2: I´ve created a  "map a network drive" and given the Z letter so my connection string is:

```
 <property name='connection.url'>jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=Z:\\database.mdb;</property>
```

But does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
<property name='connection.url'>jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=/serv-data/folder1/folder2/database.mdb;</property>
```